# How to use guild. with background tasks? discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

How to use guild. with background tasks? discord.py rewrite
For example:

```
async def create_role():
    guild = ctx.guild
    roles = ctx.guild.roles
    if game != roles:
        color = "%06x" % random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF)
        await guild.create_role(name="role name", colour=discord.Colour(color))

bot.loop.create_task(create_role())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish with this background task but here's a way to create a role in a background task.

Items/assumptions:

1. you must wait until the client is ready before guilds and roles are available.
2. Generally a background task is run in a loop until closed - I just stuck a break in there, so it is a one time action.
3. Not sure where you were getting game from, so I just put in "test01" as the role to be created.
4. Not sure about your random color process, so I just put in blue.
5. You need to know your guild ID to set the guild object
6. You get you list of roles from the guild

Code:

```
async def create_role():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while not client.is_closed():
        guild = client.get_guild(<your guild id here>)
        role_list = guild.roles
        game = 'test01'
        if game not in role_list:
            color = "%06x" % random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF)
            await guild.create_role(name=game, colour=discord.Colour.blue())
        break
```

Image with new role:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping!
It helped me code the rest of my bot and now I understand guilds even more.
The example was a small part of my create_role command (so sorry for formatting it incorrectly)
Thx again for taking your time.